# Undefined Symbols using Parse

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, x86-64

I am fairly new with Xcode and am not sure what I managed to mess up because my app was working fine and I slightly fiddled with the Frameworks, and now I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_BFExecutor", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFObject.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPush.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFEventuallyQueue.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPinningEventuallyQueue.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFCloud.o)
    objc-class-ref in Parse(PFUser.o)
```

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Could you provide some code? It's hard to diagnose otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the required frameworks to you project.

See the [documentation](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing), and in particular, step 3.

- AudioToolbox.framework
- CFNetwork.framework
- CoreGraphics.framework
- CoreLocation.framework
- MobileCoreServices.framework
- QuartzCore.framework
- Security.framework
- StoreKit.framework
- SystemConfiguration.framework
- libz.dylib
- libsqlite3.dylib